# query from multiple tables using inner joins takes long to execute

Tags: join, count

```
I have an sql query below that is taking too long to execute. kindly check the query and optimise it for me, i need to count number of files from a file_Actions table but combining it three other tables using inner join

SELECT count(*) as total 
FROM (SELECT t1.cfid as cfid,MAX(t1.timestamp) d 
FROM file_actions t1 
INNER JOIN case_files t2 ON t2.cfid=t1.cfid 
INNER JOIN case_file_allocations t3 ON t1.cfid=t3.cfid
INNER JOIN cbeta_user t4 
WHERE t4.id=t1.user_id 
AND t4.team_leader='$user' and t2.closed<>'yes' AND
t2.deleted<>1 AND
t3.reallocated<>'yes' GROUP BY t1.cfid) a 
WHERE d < '$yesterday'
```

I think it is the inner joins that causes the query to take so long to execute causing the system to slow

Answer (score 0):

Try including the `WHERE d < '$yesterday'` into the subquery `a`. Remove the fields and place the Count(*). If your tables aren't indexed on those values that you are using for conditions and relations, try to make an index.

```
SELECT count(*) as total
  FROM file_actions t1 
  INNER JOIN case_files t2 
               ON t2.cfid=t1.cfid 
  INNER JOIN case_file_allocations t3 
               ON t1.cfid=t3.cfid
  INNER JOIN cbeta_user t4 
WHERE t4.id=t1.user_id 
 AND t4.team_leader='$user' and t2.closed<>'yes' 
 AND t2.deleted<>1 
 AND t3.reallocated<>'yes' 
 AND d < '$yesterday'
GROUP BY t1.cfid
```

Recommended reading: http://www.code-fly.com/5-tips-to-make-your-sql-queries-faster/

Comment: I need to have the only the number of files from file_actions table that have its latest timestamp < $yesterday

Comment: Probably the grouping by cfid isn't also required. If it's an ID, i supose is not repeated.

Comment: d column will be unknown in your case

Comment: I see...copy paste problem.